# MEJS (Media Element JS) on play function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to write a function that hides some text that overlays a video placed on the page through MEJS (the core wordpress integration).

I'm displaying it through the `wp_video_shortcode()` function, so I'm not actually having to write any JS to get the player to display etc.

I've tried writing a bit of poor code that just checks for a click on the containing div and hides the text, then another click shows it. But I feel like I should be doing something a bit more elegant than that.

Any ideas?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$('.wp-video').on('click', function() {
    if( $('.video-title').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.video-title').fadeOut('2000');
    } else {
        $('.video-title').fadeIn('2000');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to avoid extra "if" statement

```
$('.wp-video').on('click', function() {
    $('.video-title').toggle(2000);
});
```